# Can carrierwave dynamically resize images and save them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a site where images will needed to be presented in multiple sizes. I'd like to allow users to upload an image and not have to wait for the process (or background job) to resize it into the various sizes it needs to be stored in.

Ideally, I would like to set size attributes in the view, and the first time a user renders that view, for carrier wave to generate a new resized image and serve it up at render time.

Is this possible, and if so, is there any documentation on how to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: No but you can use `minimagick` to resize.

Comment: Thanks for the resource, minimagick looks great. But I'm not sure this is a direct response to my question. I know carrierwave does not actually resize images, and instead delegates that chore to imagemagik (or minimagick I'm sure). But I assume carrier wave has view helpers... and I'm wondering if part of the API offers the functionality I described in my post.